# Looking for Drupal service to get template and processed with placeholder

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-8

In one of my PHP project, I use to configure template and write a manual script to replace placeholders with dynamic value.

I am planning to use CMS system Drupal to manage templates and consume this template by a restful service to send the email.

In restful service requests, I want to send template-id, placeholders, and value.

In Drupla I want to find a template and replace placeholders with value and send back in response.

```
<template-id>1</tempalte-id>
<properties>
    <property>
        <key>first</key>
        <value>Praveen</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <key>second</key>
        <value>Cellpoint</value>
    </property>
 <properties>
```

Is there such feature available ? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you can used preprocess hook to alter template / form values. You need to get form / template id from your html page and then print all template / form value and manipulate as per your needs.

Br,
Kapil P

Comment: /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function moduleName_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Adding custom validation for the welcome page type field.
  if ($form_id == 'node_article_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_article_form') {
    // Do some stuff.
  }
}